# Create HBASE transformations on the HUB

Tags: hbase

How can i develop generic programs which will do the following.

a.       Reading Data from HBASE
b.      Loading Data to HBASE
c.       Using HBASE Table as a Lookup in MapReduce

I need to create transformations which are generic enough and they should be easily integratable in the data pipeline.

Comment: You need to be more specific: what is HUB?  And in what way do they need to be generic?  Do you want to parameterize your jobs so that they know what table / column family / column to read from?  Given that most data workflows are fairly unique, even for the same task (e.g. doing named entity recognition on a text document), what benefit do you hope to gain by making it generic?  What specifically is not answered by looking at the HBase book?

Comment: I want to load data into the hbase table which is in any format(like:- json,xml,etc.)

Answer (score 0):

HBase stores data as byte arrays, so you can put any data in you want.  You can serialize everything to XML or JSON and treat HBase as pure blob storage.  This is actually pretty efficient, as long as you only want to query by key, or scan through a table based on keys.

One thing you lose by doing this is the ability to filter on the server side based on a row value.  For example, if you wanted all of your rows in a table of HTTP transactions from the past month (where the key is based on a timestamp), but you only want to look at rows that had an error condition (a 500 response), if you stored the response code as a column you could create a filter that only returns items with the 500 response code.  While you still have to scan through the relevant portion of your table, only the data that matches the error code will be sent over the network to your hbase client.

One way around this is to do a hybrid approach where you store your data as a serialized object (JSON / XML / whatever), and also store additional columns for things you might want to filter on.